# Regex expression to replace string with *

Tags: regex

I need to convert string like this to 
ABC_464_aDE.hmi_2df
to ABC464aDE.* that is want to remove all _ and add * at the end after dot. And my project requirement is to do this using regex. Please help to sort this out.
Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all at writing such a regular expression so far? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: *at the end after dot* Will there be only single dot or several dots?

Comment: Which language do u wanna use? have to give us more information and test case. e.g. in C# you can do `txt=Regex.Replace(txt.Replace("_",""), @"\.\w+", "");`

Comment: Yes, I am using c#.

Comment: @SukhpreetDhillon Great. I post the answer after your question so you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# the you can use this code

```
txt=Regex.Replace(txt.Replace("_",""), @"\.\w+", "");
```